# Python datetime64[ns] milliseconds get dropped when insert into ORACLE TIMESTAMP column

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc

I have an Oracle table with `TIMESTAMP(3) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column.
[table columns definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bve8f.png)
When I insert/update data the milliseconds get dropped out.

The df has a `datetime64[ns]` data with milliseconds :

```
>>>df
               MOVE_OUT_TIME         ID
967  2023-08-29 12:44:48.267  3924032.0

df.dtypes
MOVE_OUT_TIME    datetime64[ns]
ID                      float64
dtype: object
```

I'm using PyOdbc to update the db with the dataframe and this sql statement:

```
UPDATE CM_SIGAC_TRANSACTION
SET MOVE_OUT_TIME=?, UPDATE_DATE=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ID=?
```

But the updated value has zeros at the milliseconds:

```
select MOVE_OUT_TIME
  from CM_SIGAC_TRANSACTION t
 where id = 3924032

29-AUG-23 12.44.48.000 PM
```

Any thought?

I tried to update a TIMESTAMP(3) field in an ORACLE table with a datetime64[ns] value with milliseconds data, expected to see the same value in the db but the milliseconds were dropped.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the python code you are using to update the database. If you do not show us how you bind the variables into your SQL statement then there is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: A first thought is the same as above: provide a testcase.  The second thought is to use Oracle's [python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) driver instead of ODBC since it has many advantages. My third thought is that you should test this without Pandas (which I assume you're using since you mention a dataframe) to narrow down the root cause.